# Handling button event from another class in Jframe

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am using netbeans to make a GUI. To make it simple, let say what I want to do is that when I press a button it just opens a new JFrame and print a text on a JPanel, a text entered by the user.

It sounds easy if I just complete the automatically generated function from Netbeans :

```
private void popUpButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // I added these three lines                                         
    JFrame newFrame = new myPopUpWindow();
    myPopupWindow.getTextLabel().setText("Hello" + enteredText.getText());
    this.dispose();
}
```

And everything works as I want. Now what I want to do is having a cleaner code. I want to put these two line in a class `ButtonHandler.java` in a function `handleHelloPopUp(String enteredStringText)` Now comes the dilemma:

- If I make `handleHelloPopUp` static, I get some error when I access some non static variable
- If I don't make `handleHelloPopUp` I just have to pass it as argument in my Jframe -> horrible code structure

What is the best way to do this ? Please help ...

Comment: Rather than learning the idiosyncracies of a GUI builder, why not just learn Swing?  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc OT: While I'm sure your comment was made with good intentions, blindly suggesting that the user adopts a completely different approach is not respectful or constructive, and does absolutely nothing to help them with their specific problem. I frequently see comments similar to yours where the OP (often a student) responds that they are _required_ to use a certain tool/language/version/approach/IDE. So extend the OP the courtesy of first asking if they are _required_ to use NetBeans for the GUI before dismissing their approach, and if they do not respond to you just let it go.

Comment: I think I found a solution to my problem, and it is using the netbeans GUI builder. In handleHelloPopUp, I just pass the JFrame as argument and modify it. It is not the best approach but it works ... Thus I can seperate the view and the controller in different packages

Comment: @rudeus123 It's good that you solved your problem, but it is more helpful to the community if you explain the resolution in an answer rather than a comment. Be sure to show the code you changed.